# No table found error in SQlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a problem with SQlite. Whenever I execute Queries it goes fine but when I exit by .exit command and open again and execute Select * form emp statement, it renders no table even though I use begin transaction and commit .

Any help please. I'm new to SQLite.
Thanks
Bamadeva

Comment: still it doesn't work friend. Another Qsn is there that "How can a user be created for QSLite database" like as scott triger in Oracle.

Comment: what's the output for that command?

Comment: when I exit the sqlite prompt and again open to see the database details it shows no such table found. Is there any solution for this problem. Thanks friend for your valuable time to help me out.

Comment: `sqlite3 \path\to\yourdatabase.sqlite3`    `.schema;`    what's the output?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:-

Wherever our database is created, in my case it is :-

C:\Sites\databases>

Since my database is contactlist_development, I should have entered it with the following commands:-

C:\Sites\databases>sqlite3 contactlist_development

This takes me to :-

sqlite>.schema

Then i am able to view the table details which i just created:)